# why do vertices need to have properties for edges?

Tags: orientdb

I found the discussion at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/Y0QJiXk7d1I to be very useful to help me set up a strict schema with edges in it. This is my code

```
val fileLink = schema.createClass(DefinedInS.label, g.getEdgeBaseType())
fileLink.setStrictMode(true)
fileLink.createProperty("out", OType.LINK, fqnSymbol).setNotNull(true)
fileLink.createProperty("in", OType.LINK, fileCheck).setNotNull(true)
fqnSymbol.createProperty("out_" + DefinedInS.label, OType.LINKBAG).setNotNull(true)
fileCheck.createProperty("in_" + DefinedInS.label, OType.LINKBAG).setNotNull(true)
```

but I am confused why I need the last two lines at all, aren't they redundant (or at least implied by the `fileLink` properties?). Could somebody please explain why they are needed?

In addition, for this example I want **exactly one** link from a `fqnSymbol` to a `fileCheck` but this seems to required that `LINKBAG` is used (it fails if I use `LINK`). Is that something I should be allowed to do?

Futhermore, is there any performance benefit to be gained from adding an index on the edge? My usecase is such that I will always have a `fqnSymbol` at hand when I want to lookup a `fileCheck`.

I raised https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5494 to request better documentation in this area.

Answer (score 0):

When one creates an edge (that is, an instance of E), the points of connection are stored at both endpoints (the vertices):

```
(vertex) -> [edge] -> (vertex)
```

It's my understanding that if the edge is an immediate instance of E, then those endpoints are properties named `out_` and `in_`.  (Similarly, if they are immediate instances of some subclass, say EE, of E, then they would be named `out_EE` and `in_EE`.) Often these details don't matter (e.g. outE() collects all outgoing edges), but sometimes they do (as when defining constraints on properties).

Regarding the multiplicity constraint:

> I want exactly one link from a fqnSymbol to a fileCheck ...

This constraint can be enforced (at least to a degree) using MIN and MAX:

```
alter property fqnSymbol.out_ MIN 1;
alter property fqnSymbol.out_ MAX 1;
```

(Fortunately, the MIN and MAX constraints won't prevent an fqnSymbol vertex from being created in the first place :-)

Tighter enforcement may require writing hooks or triggers.